# Is possible to retrieve all tree under a work item using a Wiql query

Tags: azure-devops, wiql, azure-boards

Is it possible to retrieve all childs from a Work Item in Azure Boards?
I have the following structure:

- Milestone

  - Feature (child)

    - Development PBI 1 (child)

      - Development PBI 2 (successor)

        - ... (successor)

          - Development PBI N (successor)

This is the query that I made so far:

```
SELECT
      [System.Id],
      [System.WorkItemType],
      [System.Title],
      [System.AssignedTo],
      [System.State]
FROM workitemLinks
WHERE
      (
              [Source].[System.Id] = 41064
      )
      AND
      (
              [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = "Milestone"
      )
      AND (
              [System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward'
      )
ORDER BY [System.Id]
MODE (Recursive)
```

However, is only retrieving up to the third level, that is Milestone, Feature and Development PBI 1

Comment: Do you have 2 link types: child and successor?

Comment: Yes, child and successor. I solved it in my program by creating a recursive method to retrieve all the successors

Comment: You can post here the answer and accept it :)